# Why a generic class implementing an interface doesn't need constructors?

Tags: java, generics, interface

Here are the sample codes in my lecture which define a generic class called BasicLinkedList class using another class ListNode.

I do understand that interface doesn't need constructor, but why BasicLinkedList as a class implementing an interface doesn't need constructor as well?

Below is code for ListNode class:

```
class ListNode<E> {
  protected E element;
  protected ListNode<E> next;

  public ListNode(E item) {element = item; next = null;}
  public ListNode(E item, ListNode <E> n) {element = item; next = n;}

  public ListNode<E> getNext() {return this.next;}

  public E getElement() {return this.element;} 
}
```

Code for the LinkedListInterface:

```
import java.util.*;

public interface LinkedListInterface<E> {
  public boolean isEmpty();
  public int size();
  public E getFirst() throws NoSuchElementException;
  public boolean contains(E item);
  public void addFirst(E item);
  public E removeFirst() throws NoSuchElementException;
  public void print() throws NoSuchElementException;
}
```

Finally the code for BasicLinkedList:

```
import java.util.*;
class BasicLinkedList<E> implements LinkedListInterface<E> {
  protected ListNode <E> head = null;
  protected int num_nodes = 0;

  public boolean isEmpty() {return (num_nodes == 0); }
...//other methods
```

Comment: No classes _have_ to have a constructor written in the code. The compiler will add a default one if none is found. Is there something specific that made you think they were required?

Comment: `BasicLinkedList` has a default constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to provide any [`constructors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) for your class, but you must be careful when doing this. The compiler automatically provides a no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to with generics, when you don't define a constructor, Java will provide a one for you with the following signature,

```
public YourClass(){
}
```

Once you define your own constructor, that default constructor will go away.

Answer (score 0):

When there is no constructor defined, JAVA provides implicitly a default constructor without parameters

```
public ClassName(){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class YourClass {


}
```

suppose that this is your created class the compiler creates ( at run time ) 
a default constructors , so basicly it's not naccessary to define  it in your code

hope it helped :D